# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia return NotReadableError: Could not start video source

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem when accessing my webcam through my web app. i following the example code to how to accessing webcam in [MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia). but when i try to run my web app, it shows error `NotReadableError: Could not start video source` in chrome console.

my web app run with https, on desktop google chrome version 81.04 and chromium rasbian version 78.0. it doesn't work with my built in laptop webcam and my raspberry pi with logitech webcam

does anyone has a solution ? thanks in advance !

this is my code.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <video id="video-input"></video>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var video = document.getElementById('video-input');

 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video:true, audio:false})
  .then(function(stream){
   video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error occurred! " + err);
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN, in the page you linked in your question:

> **`NotReadableError`**
>
> Although the user granted permission to use the matching devices, a hardware error occurred at the operating system, browser, or Web page level which prevented access to the device.

This is a problem that happens between the browser and the device. It might be because of the driver. Your example works for me (not in the Stack Snippet), so I can't tell you what's exactly happening and how to solve it.

I would recommend you updating your drivers.

Comment: do you mean my intel graphics driver ?

Answer (score 1):

It may be the camera is already being used by another process